# Maven archetype to create Micro Service application

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, microservices

Is there such Maven Archetype that create multi module Maven project structure for Micro Service application? I want to get a Rest API skeleton
based on Spring Boot and Docker.

Comment: https://start.spring.io, select what you want, download, import...